# Python - Printing unicode to console window with WConio

Tags: python, winapi, console, conio

I'm writing a terminal game in python. It has a map loader function, normally it works fine when I use regular characters in the map. (abcdefg) but when I use something like █, and save the map as 'ansi', it renders it as a half solid. When I change the encoding to unicode, the display is scrambled with output such as ^a^a^a^a^a and the like. When I save it as unicode big endian or unicode little endian, it doesn't display the map at all. I'm wondering what's going on. Can anyone help, or am I posting this in the wrong section?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use:`x=ord(character)`
That will allow you to get the ASCII value, then you can use:`print chr(x)` and it should give you the character that you need.